# React Hooks - Hamburger Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, hamburger-menu

I am trying to use React Hooks in order to implement a hamburger menu on my project website but am greeted with a few different errors in the console. The menu is just visible to start and the button has no effect.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `open` of type `object` supplied to `Burger`, expected `boolean`.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `setOpen` of type `object` supplied to `Burger`, expected `function`.

> Uncaught TypeError: setOpen is not a function

Please see code below:

**Burger.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { bool, func } from 'prop-types';
import { StyledBurger } from './BurgerStyles';

const Burger = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  return (
    <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      <div />
      <div />
      <div />
    </StyledBurger>
  )
}
Burger.propTypes = {
    open: bool.isRequired,
    setOpen: func.isRequired,
  };

export default Burger;
```

**Menu.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { bool } from 'prop-types';
import { StyledMenu } from "./MenuStyles";

const Menu = ({ open }) => {
    return (
      <StyledMenu open={open}>
          CONTENT
      </StyledMenu>
    )
  }
  Menu.propTypes = {
    open: bool.isRequired,
  }
  export default Menu;
```

Movement of menu.js is handled in styled component using:

```
transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)'};
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Menu from "./components/Menu/Menu";

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    <Menu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    <Header open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    </>
  )
  }

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Burger from '../Burger/Burger';


const Header = (open, setOpen) => (
        <div>
            <Burger open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
        </div>
)
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Be aware that `bool.isRequired` means that the prop must always be true and present. Which kinda doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Header.js`, the props are not being destructured, so `open` is actually the `props` object.

```js
// It should be this
const Header = ({ open, setOpen }) => (

// Not this
const Header = (open, setOpen) => (
```